# How do you make a 'NOT LIKE' filter in Chainsaw?

Tags: log4j, apache-chainsaw

For example, I have a filter: MSG LIKE QueryAdvisor.*
and I want to change it to see all of the events that do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:
! ( msg like QueryAdvisor.* )

Note the use of parens around the expression being negated..

Try out the latest developer snapshot here, which doesn't require spaces around operators and operands or spaces around parens..

http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: OK, I had the parens but was missing the spaces. I think I'll check out the latest from the chainsaw repo instead.